# Replace partial matching string with bold string

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace matched parts of a string by bold strings.

```
const str = 'This is an Example';
const term = 'exam';
```

Now I would like to get the result

```
This is an <strong>Exam</strong>ple
```

I tried to use an regEx, but this seams to have a wrong syntax and also with this the uppercase of *Example* would be ignored:

```
const result = str.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(term), 'g'), '<strong>' + term + '</strong>');
```

Comment: Use the flag `gi`, not only `g`. What does `escapeRegExp` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to capture with case insensitivity you need to include the `i` flag. Also, if you want to preserve the original case rather than replacing it with the case of `term`, you can use a capture group as follows:

```js
const str = 'This is an Example';
const term = 'exam';
const result = str.replace(new RegExp(`(${term})`, 'gi'), '<strong>$1</strong>');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `i` flag on expression:

**Perform case-insensitive matching**

```
  new RegExp(term, 'gi')
```